# Should Isaiah 55:10 by considered as Messianic or alluding to the Messianic age?

Tags: hebrew, isaiah

> “For as the rain and the snow come down from heaven
>       and do not return there but water the earth,
>   making it **bring forth** and sprout,
>       giving seed to the sower and bread to the eater, (Isaiah 55:10) [ESV]
>
> כי כאשר ירד הגשם והשלג מן־השמים ושמה לא ישוב כי אם־הרוה את־הארץ **והולידה** והצמיחה ונתן זרע לזרע ולחם לאכל

The word "bring forth" is from [יָלַד](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H3205&t=KJV) which is almost always used in bringing forth children and an unusual way to describe the agricultural effect of rain. For example:

> “If you walk in my statutes and observe my commandments and do them, then I will give you your rains in their season, and the land shall yield its increase, and the trees of the field shall yield their fruit. (Leviticus 26:3-4)

Obedience will result in rains and the land (הָאָ֙רֶץ֙ as in Isaiah) will yield its increase.

Rain in Isaiah is to be compared with the word of the LORD, which like the Word in [John's prologue](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%201%3A1-18&version=ESV) is sent and returns:

> so shall my word be that goes out from my mouth;
>       it shall not return to me empty,
>   but it shall accomplish that which I purpose,
>       and shall succeed in the thing for which I sent it.
>   (Isaiah 55:11)

Should Isaiah 55:10 be seen as Messianic and the use of יָלַד as alluding to children of God? Or is there a different explanation why rain and snow will water the earth to "bring forth?"

Comment: Good catch. +1 In the Greek, it is a rarely used word that appears to map to the English word "spawn". IE: To give birth to a large  brood at one time, like fish do, rather than birthing a single child.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly seems possible in the context.

Isaiah 50:1 "The Lord says, “All you who are thirsty, come and drink"

John 7:37 "Jesus stood up and said in a loud voice, “Let anyone who is thirsty come to me and drink."

Isaiah 50:3 "Come to me and listen, listen to me so you may live. I will make an agreement with you that will last forever I will give you the blessings I promised to David"

Acts 13:34 "As for the fact that He raised Him up from the dead, no longer to return to decay, He has spoken in this way: ‘I will give you the holy and sure blessings of David."

It seems snow and rain definitely have a deeper meaning behind them. In Proverbs 26:1 snow is said to not be fitting for the summer and rain not fitting for the harvest. While Job 24:19 says "Drought and heat consume the snow waters, So does Sheol those who have sinned."

Drought and Heat being equal to summer would be comparative to The Grave (Sheol) and of course Isaiah 1:18 “Though your sins are as scarlet, They will be as white as snow" it seems snow is meant to be understood as White which is to become pure. So Snow would come from the heavens to bring purification. To those who are consumed by Their sins (Drought)

Now Rain seems like it can also be used for purification but there is definitely the possibility it is symbolic of a Spiritual Birth, I suppose Purification and a Spiritual Birth can be one in the same since you can't have one without the other.

It says Rain is not fitting for The Harvest, which in many cases The Harvest is the Second coming of The Lord when we will be "Caught Up" into The Sky with him. I suppose the understanding is that once The Harvest comes The Purification and Rebirth will come to a Hault

Looking into it, it definitely seems Messianic.